# Odoo Buttons in Grid (One2Many Fields) Odoo 8

Tags: odoo-8

Good Day! I have a problem in Odoo's  button I've created Treeview in XML with a button to get the ID of the selected records here's a sample code

XML

```
    <notebook>
    <page string ="Employee's Payroll">
        <data>
            <field name="payroll_main_id" string ="" attrs="{'readonly':[('state', '!=', 'draft')]}" >
                <tree create = "false" editable="bottom/top">
                    <field name ="id"  readonly="1" invisible="0"/>
                    <field name ="name" readonly="1"/>
                    <field name ="employee_id" readonly="1" />
                    <button name = "%(action_incentive_wiz_breakdown)d"
                        string ="Breakdown"
                        type = "action"
                        context = "{'default_payroll_detail_id': id,
                                    'default_other_type': 1}"/>
                    <field name ="tardiness" />
                </tree>
            </field>
        </data>
    </page>
</notebook>
```

The Button will call the Wizard form and its needed the ID of the selected (when a button has been click) records, the problem is the last ID will always been used in referencing in wizard (the first ID of the button click). can someone help me with this problem thanks.

heres the Wizard form 
XML

```
         <record id="view_incentive_wiz_breakdown" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">payroll.incentive.main.wiz.form</field>
        <field name="model">payroll.incentive.main.wiz</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Incentive Breakdown" create="false" edit="false">
            <sheet>
                <group string ="Information">
                    <field name="other_type" readonly="1"/>
                    <field name="payroll_detail_id" />
                    <field name="name" />
                </group>
                <notebook>
                    <page string ="Breakdown">
                        <data>
                            <field name="incentive_ids">
                                <tree create = "false" editable="bottom/top">
                                    <field name="name" readonly="1"/>
                                    <field name="amount"/>
                                </tree>
                            </field>
                        </data>
                    </page>
                </notebook>
            </sheet>
            <footer>
                <button name="updateReliever" string="Save" type="object" class="oe_highlight"/> or
                <button string="Cancel" special="cancel" class="oe_link"/>
            </footer>
        </form>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record id="action_incentive_wiz_breakdown" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Reliever Attendance</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">payroll.incentive.main.wiz</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">form</field>
        <field name="target">new</field>
        <field name="nodestroy">True</field>
    </record>
```